# Error in pyspark in window10 with python in sc = SparkContext("local", "SparkFile App")

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am looking for help after so many searches in google and still not able to solve my problem.

I am trying to install pyspark package in python 3.6.7 and IDE I am using anaconda (64 bit) and running my code in spyder and have window 10 pro 64 bit operating system.

I followed almost all website and tried doing same to install pyspark but still getting error while setting SparkContext("local", "SparkFile App"). It seems to me that it is Java error but no idea what should I do with it.

Below are my folder structure for installation

For Java

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191
```

For Spark (spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7)

```
C:\spark
```

For Python

```
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3
```

Environment which I set

```
SPARK_HOME=C:\spark

HADOOP_HOME=C:\spark

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter

PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook

PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe

PATH=C:\Users\user\Anaconda3;C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\user\Anaco
nda3\Library\bin;C:\spark\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin;C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src;C:\spark\python\lib\pyspark;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\py4j;%SPARK_HOME%\python\lib\pyspark;C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

I think I have tried almost all method which is available on websites and given above set-up is my last time effort. My Path and environment may be wrong,but not sure about correct way.

It would be great help, if someone help me to understand in layman language.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Edit:
Below is error which I am getting

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "count app")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<ipython-input-1-520a7abb0d94>", line 2, in <module>
 sc = SparkContext("local", "count app")

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 118, in __init__
conf, jsc, profiler_cls)

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py", line 188, in _do_init
self._javaAccumulator = self._jvm.PythonAccumulatorV2(host, port)

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1525, in __call__
answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 332, in get_return_value
format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JError: An error occurred while calling 
None.org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Constructor 
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2([class 
java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist
at   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:179)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:196)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:237)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error trace?

Comment: @sramalingam24, I have added my error log.